# How to decompose a sprite in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I am trying to decompose [this sprite](https://github.com/lucasnfe/Science-Birds/blob/master/Assets/Sprites/Foreground/blocks.png) into separate image files. The metadata for the sprite is [here](https://github.com/lucasnfe/Science-Birds/blob/master/Assets/Sprites/Foreground/blocks.png.meta). I opened the project in Unity but couldn't find out how to decompose the sprites into separate files.

Since there is a metadata file that has the information for sprite position, width and height, no auto-detection is needed. All I need is a program that's gonna read the metadata file, find the sprite position, width and height data and extract the sprites from the image file.

Answer (score 3):

Unity3D has shipped this function with its [SpriteEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html):

> Automatic Slicing
>
> Isolating the sprite rectangles manually works well but in many cases, Unity can save you work by detecting the graphic elements and extracting them for you automatically. If you click on the Slice menu in the control bar, you will see this panel:

[image]

Below include some other(programmatic) solutions as well:

- https://github.com/toxicFork/Unity3D-TextureAtlasSlicer
- Since Unity 2017.3, you can also use
  `InternalSpriteUtility.GenerateAutomaticSpriteRectangles` to
  automatically slice up a texture into sprites during
  [OnPostprocessTexture](https://forum.unity.com/threads/sprite-editor-automatic-slicing-by-script.320776/#post-2508880).
- [AutoSpriteSlicer.cs](https://gist.github.com/shadesbelow/8a6ddc54db795241f3cff539db6ea487)

Comment: I clicked the "Slice" menu and that pop-up shows but I don't know what to do after that. I am trying to save the sliced sprites as separate images.

Comment: There is also a metadata file that has the information for sprite position, width and height. Hence, no auto-detection is needed. All I need is a program that's gonna read the metadata file, find the sprite position, width and height data and extract the sprites from the image file.

Comment: Why do you need separate sprites? Unity itself can handle multiple sprite assets in one file just fine.